# Internal server error when RDP to Windows 10 VM unless already logged in

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, hyper-v, rdp

We have a Windows server Hyper-V running Server 2012 R2 which has a Windows 10 VM on it. This VM is for 1 user to remote into.

Recently we have an issue where when they try to RDP it gives the error: "Internal Server Error". It does this until you go onto the Hyper-V, connect to the VM and login with the users details.

I have made sure that the "remote desktop services" service is set to "automatic" and the issue still occurs.

Any advice would be fantastic!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message (a screenshot would be better, if available) because "Internal Server Error" doesn't seems to be a RDP-related error message.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't get chance to grab a screenshot. It definitely said "Internal server Error" though as I saw this with my owns eyes. However, I have got it working again by restarting the VM. Not an actual fix as this will likely come back, but it's better than having to log the user in every day!